# sending udp packet from WAN to a local computer without setting port forwarding on router C++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock, winsock2

I have a server with a public IP, I want to send some UDP Packet data from the server over the WAN to a computer connected behind a router.  I have the public IP of my home connection and I have the public IP of the server, I am also able to get the MAC addresses if necessary.  I am using Windows Sockets for this.  I know this can all be done via port forwarding on the router which I did and everything is working fine, but I want to know how this can be done through C++ code.

Applications like utorrent or Skype are able to send data directly to a PC from the WAN through the router and to my computer without having to port forward.  Just wondering how this is all done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to read a bit about tcp/ip and its implications
"TCP/IP Illustrated, Vol. 1: The Protocols" would be a good start

Comment: Do you want to initiate connection from some machine _to_ machine behind the NAT? Are you looking for something like [NAT-PMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_Port_Mapping_Protocol)?

Answer (score 3):

For TCP, you don't have to do a thing. Just initiate the connection *from* the PC. The router will know the responses has to be routed back to the PC.

UDP is tricky you as you need router support. Applications typically use [NAT-PMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_Port_Mapping_Protocol) to achieve this. The wikipedia entry mentions both uTorrent and Skype. If you want to see how they do it listen on UDP port 5351.

There's another technique called [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) which requires a third party which is directly addressable by both sides.

Comment: so I dont quite understand, UDP is connection-less, and when I send data from the server I have to specify an IP, the only IP I can provide is the public IP of the router on the client side.

Comment: oh I'm sorry I was sloppy, thought it's TCP. see update.